# Find the posterior of $\theta$.

Tags: probability, statistics, bayesian

$\theta \sim \text{ Uniform}(0,1)$ and $X|\theta \sim \text{ Bernoulli}(\theta)$.

How would I find the posterior of $\theta$?

---

The likelihood of a Bernoulli is $p^{\sum{x_i}} (1-p)^{n-\sum x_i}$. How do I proceed? It is supposed to fit the beta distribution but I don't see how since it doesn't have a B-1

Comment: Do you know Bayes Theorem? What do you mean by "it doesn't have a B-1"? Tried editing but very hard to interpret.

Comment: The pdf of a beta distribution is Gamma(a+B)/G(a)G(b)*θ^(a-1)*(1-θ)^(b-1). I don't see how to make it fit the beta distribution.

Comment: How many questions are you asking? Do you really understand what problem you are facing? The question is not at all a "distribution fitting" problem.

Comment: How would I find the posterior then?

Comment: Yes, *find*, instead of *fit* is the correct verb. I will restate your problem and give an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are given observations $X = \{X_1, \ldots, X_n\}$ with $X_i|\Theta = \theta \sim \text{ Bernoulli}(\theta)$, which gives the likelihood function of $\Theta$ as follows:
$$\ell(x|\Theta = \theta) = \theta^{\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i}(1 - \theta)^{n - \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i} = \theta^t(1 - \theta)^{n - t},$$
where $t = \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i$.

The prior of $\Theta$, by condition has pdf
$$\pi_\Theta(\theta) = I_{(0, 1)}(\theta).$$
Therefore the joint distribution of $X$ and $\theta$ is given by
$$p(x, \theta) = \ell(x|\theta)\pi_\Theta(\theta) = \theta^t(1 - \theta)^{n - t}I_{(0, 1)}(\theta)$$
Notice by Bayesian theorem, the posterior distribution of $\Theta$ given $X = x$ is
$$p_{\Theta|X}(\theta|x) = \frac{p(x, \theta)}{\int p(x, \theta) d\theta} \propto p(x, \theta). \tag{1}$$
where $\propto$ means two expressions differ only up to a constant which is independent of $\theta$.

It can be identified $p(x, \theta)$ is the pdf of $\text{Beta}(t + 1, n - t + 1)$ distribution, Thus by $(1)$, we claim that
$$\Theta|X = x \sim \text{ Beta}\left(\sum x_i + 1, n - \sum x_i + 1\right).$$

Comment: Would the above answer (to yours) be incorrect?

Comment: They are the same, his $k$ is my $t = \sum x_i$.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you call *Bernoulli* distribution should be called *binomial* distribution based on the context.

Let
\begin{align*}
h(\theta)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if $\theta\in(0,1)$,}\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
\end{align*}
denote the prior probability density function of $\theta$ and $f(\theta\,|\,X)$ denote the posterior probability density function. Using Bayes’s rule, one has for any $k\in\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$ that
\begin{align*}
f(\theta\,|\,X=k)=\frac{\mathbb P(X=k\,|\,\theta)\,h(\theta)}{\int \mathbb P(X=k\,|\,t)\,h(t)\,\mathrm dt}=\frac{\binom{n}{k}\theta^k(1-\theta)^{n-k}}{\int_0^1 \binom{n}{k}t^k(1-t)^{n-k}\,\mathrm dt}=\frac{\theta^k(1-\theta)^{n-k}}{\beta(k+1,n-k+1)}
\end{align*}
(where $\beta$ denotes the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)), which is a [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) with parameters $k+1$ and $n-k+1$ supported on the interval $(0,1)$.